# Conditional field rendering in oracle apex forms

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table 'arrear students'. And i want to create a form on it but the input fields must only appear on the form upon certain conditions like if the previosuly stored value in the field was null it must appear or else it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a form on your table
- Each column will be a page item
- To set a display condition for a page item, go to "Server Side Condition" and pick the appropriate condition for your requirement (eg if value NULL - pick "Item = NULL")